# Variation with respect to the metric and other tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-calculus

When varying an action with respect to tensors and the metric, I'm afraid I get confused as how to one organizes the Lagrangian and then performs the variation. Take for example, the following example from:

http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.22.1915

They have a Lagrangian density (from Eq. 22):

[image: lagrangian density]

(a is a constant). They vary with respect to the metric and contorsion tensor. When they vary with respect to [image: metric], they get:

[image: variation with respect to metric]

When they vary with respect to [image: contorsion], they get:

[image: variation with respect to contorsion]

I have two questions:

1) How did they arrive at these expressions?

2) More importantly, can anyone refer me to an example where someone does something similar, which lays out the steps clearly? I already am aware of many that vary the Ricci scalar with respect to the metric to get Einstein's equations, and I feel I have a good understanding of that. But once you have other tensors (like the contorsion in this case), I don't see it.

Comment: It appears there is a type-o in the paper. In the variation with respect to $g_{\mu\nu}$, there is a lone $\sigma$ index left (after contraction of other indices) in the last term and two $a$'s left on top. There should only be $a$ and $b$ left in the first variation, and $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the second. I'm assuming the second $a$ in that term is supposed to a be a $\sigma$. I've edited the question as such, but note it's different than the paper.